# CSS: Cannot horizontally center by using margin

Tags: html, css, center-align

I have tried to using `margin: 0 auto;` to horizontally center the div elements however I don't understand why the items are always appearing on the left of the HTML page.

```css
body {
    background: #f06d06;
    font-size: 80%;
}

main {
     display: inline-block;
     background: white;
     line-height: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     margin: 20px auto;
     width: 300px;
     resize: vertical;
     overflow: auto;
     vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;    
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <main>
        <div>
            <p>center align</p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: add your code as snippet

Answer (score 0):

set text-align:center to main.

```
main{
display: inline-block;
background: white;
line-height: 300px;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
resize: vertical;
overflow: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and i have tried, it works somehow. But i still have questions: 1) why using margin: 0, auto; cannot center the div this time? 2) I want the whole block to be in the center of the HTML page; 3) text-align is only for text element only? Yes, it works to the div element in this case, but i just little bit confuse because as i learnt before text-align is only for text..maybe i am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

**Try This, I Changed div display properties**

```css
body {
    background: #f06d06;
    font-size: 80%;
}

main {
     display: inline-block;
     background: white;
     line-height: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     margin: 20px auto;
     width: 300px;
     resize: vertical;
     overflow: auto;
     vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;    
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <main>
        <div>
            <p>center align</p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: if you need to align whole div to center try flexbox

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background: #f06d06;
    font-size: 80%;
}

main {
     display: block;
     background: white;
     line-height: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     margin: 20px auto;
     width: 300px;
     resize: vertical;
     overflow: auto;
     vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div>
      <p>Center div</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Okay, let me explain what is happening over here, you in your post add display inline-block which I changed to block, which means that a particular element `main` will take up the whole horizontal space, and when you use `margin: auto` it automatically gives equal margin to both sides, it is working on your code but the thing is you haven't specified the width to the max.

So, whenever you want to center the element using `margin: auto`, you need to specify the width as `100vh` or `100%`(if parent div has `100vh`)

Comment: Somehow i understand your logic, block occupied the whole horizontal space.  However, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align, there tell me that the vertical-align is used for inline, inline-block, table-cell only.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a **flexbox** or **Grid** to achieve vertical and horizontal centering! Here I little update on you code

```css
body {
    background: #f06d06;
    font-size: 80%;
}

main {
     display: block;
     background: white;
     line-height: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     margin: 20px auto;
     width: 300px;
     resize: vertical;
     overflow: auto;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin:auto;
     overflow:hidden;
}

div {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
}

p {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;    
        text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <main>
        <div>
            <p>center align</p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```